# Cannot spot the difference between these two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to clean up a long query I have come up with a modified version, but now the old query with certain parameters returns 6 rows, but my version returns none. I have been straining my eyes to spot the difference but cannot find any. Here are the `WHERE` clauses from the two versions with identical set of parameters:

**The ugly (but working) version:**

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table as a
WHERE 1=1 
and a.title LIKE '%Manager%' 
and a.status='Approved'  
and (a.effected_date<=now()) 
and ( 
    (DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= now() AND a.is_hotjob=0) 
     or 
    (DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= now() AND a.is_hotjob=1)
)
```

**My cleaned (but broken) version:**

```
SELECT ...
FROM `table`  AS `a`
WHERE CONCAT(`a`.`title`, ' | ', `a`.`job_detail_section`) LIKE '%Manager%' AND 
`a`.`status` = 'Approved' AND 
`a`.`effected_date` <= '2013-12-30' AND 
(`a`.`effected_date` >= '2013-11-30' OR `a`.`is_hotjob` = '1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the last AND/OR backwards:

```
`a`.`effected_date` <= '2013-12-30' OR 
(`a`.`effected_date` >= '2013-11-30' AND `a`.`is_hotjob` = '1')
```

EDIT: after reformatting, the answer looks more like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM `table`  AS `a`
WHERE CONCAT(`a`.`title`, ' | ', `a`.`job_detail_section`) LIKE '%Manager%' AND 
`a`.`status` = 'Approved' AND 
`a`.`effected_date` <= now() AND 
`a`.`effected_date` >= DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

and POSSIBLY:

```
AND `a`.`is_hotjob` IN (0,1)
```

Comment: I'd think that the `OR` should be *inside* the parenthesis.  I don't think this will work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Just look at the previous query. Does the same thing: `or (DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= now()  AND a.is_hotjob=1) )`

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  Problem is, `a AND b OR c` might not work the way he expects.

Comment: True, and I suspect that's why he's having such a hard time parsing it.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, parentheses are your friends :)

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure yet, but will try to digest this. This is legacy code and not documented. I think the proper logic would be *Select rows not older than 30 days unless they are a hot job*. Now, does this version embody this logic?

Comment: OK I just edited your question and reformatted the "old ugly" query... should make more sense this way.

Comment: Hard to see what the original coder's intention has been, but after your (helpful) reformatting it looks to me the last `and` is equal to just `DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= now()` and we would completely disregard `a.is_hotjob` -- isn't it so?

Comment: Yes, assuming `a.is_hotjob` is always either 0 or 1 it seems useless.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour so your real problem seems to be that you subtracted 30 days instead of adding...

Answer (score 0):

As a substitute of-

```
(DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= now() AND a.is_hotjob=0) 
 or 
(DATE_ADD(a.effected_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= now() AND a.is_hotjob=1)
```

You could use the following-

```
(`a`.`effected_date` >= '2013-11-30' AND `a`.`is_hotjob` in (0, 1))
```

But according to the additional info i.e. `a.is_hotjob` has value either `0` or `1` then there is no need to mention it in the condition at all. So basically the following format will be sufficient-

```
`a`.`effected_date` >= '2013-11-30'
```

Comment: Yes, as it is `is_hotjob` is not taken into account with the old query which is wrong, because the only valid values for that column is `0` or `1`.